# Is it possible for an extended ('gaming') keypad to not duplicate keyboard keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard, gaming, key-binding

I've been looking for an extended keypad, often called gaming keypads.  These are like half keyboards that sit off to one side and can be used with one-hand.  [This is an example](https://smile.amazon.com/keyboard-One-Handed-Mechanical-Keyboard-SADES/dp/B07D6NTPWH/).  I have no experience with these at all, but wish to try using one both for gaming, and in one or two other programs that allow me to map keybinds.

One trait that every extended keypad I've seen so far shares is that they duplicate the left 4-5 columns of keyboard keys.  This seems to defeat the purpose to me, as the point of the extra device is to provide *additional* keys I can bind.  If the 'C' on the keypad performs the same function as the 'C' on the keyboard, then I have not gained any extra keys.

Is there anything in Windows that limits the number of key input values forcing manufacturers to reuse keyboard keys?  If not, what causes manufacturers to do this?

Comment: "This seems to defeat the purpose to me, as the point of the extra device is to provide additional keys I can bind." - How did you come to this conclusion?  It seems like the purpose of the keyboard is to simply provide an alternative hand placement.

Comment: These are not macro keyboards, but gaming keyboards - ie. keyboards (supposedly) optimized for games. There's no added value in using keys not present on a standard keyboard for this purpose. Quite the opposite, using the WASD area of a standard keyboard makes it immediately compatible with most games.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you want is to use a midi device and a midi-to-key driver to program and translate the inputs to keystrokes.

Poke around a little by googling midi drumpad devices with a 4 x 4 grid of large pads and open source midi-to-keystroke loopback device or drivers.

Comment: i have used, in the past, a midi expression pedal as a joystick input (gas pedal for driving game) with an open source midi-to-joystick loopback device